# Use normal HTML Button to call Controller in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to use normal HTML Button to call Controller in ASP.NET MVC2, instead of ActionLink, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically with a button, you'll either use javascript to invoke the action or wrap it in a form (or both).

```
<% Html.BeginForm( "action", "controller", new { id = Model.ID } )
   { %>
     <button type="submit">Go</button>
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $('button').click( function() {
              var form = $('form');
              $.post( form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
              });
              return false; // don't really submit the form
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can specify the `method` of the form to be `get` and then give a `type` for the button of `submit`. Then you need no javascript at all.

Comment: @Garry -- it's just an example to demonstrate.  Likely I'd do some sort of validation or something with AJAX instead with the javascript, but I wanted something simple.  Nice to note that there are better ways of accomplishing it, though.  I should have specified the type, though.  IE probably wouldn't react properly in the absence of javascript without it.  Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just use `Url.Action()` to render the URL to the action.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Action") %>">BLA BLA</a>
```

or

```
<button onclick="javascript: window.location = '<%= Ajax.JavascriptEncode(Url.Action("Action")) %> '">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please don't embed your javascript in a tag.  It's a bad/hard to maintain practice. Note also that this won't work if javascript is turned off or you have an javascript error on the page.

Comment: I know this, but just showed it as an example. He said ActionLink (an A element) , but also mentioned HTML button (a BUTTON element) . So for completeness sake, I added both.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="get" action="YourUrl">
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Or click me" />
</form>
```

You will probably want to use the `<%= Url.Action(...) %>` helper methods to determine the `action` URL for the form.

This requires no javascript to function but will get the appearance you are looking for. The `button` tags can be styled a bit more that the `input` type but it depends what existing styles you might have as to which one you use. They are functionally identical.